# Timestamp ou datetime calcular lifetime/diferenca (php)

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

Olá, estou tentando aqui como fazer pra esse valor
"147878163" ser convertido pra "1 dia 17 horas 15 minutos" por exemplo

Aparentemente é timestamp, mas esse valor é diferente do que eu costumo usar, porque convertendo pra datetime é de 40 anos atrás... 
Porém no sistema mostra que o serviço tá sendo usado a 1 dia 17 horas....
E quando eu uso a API pra resgatar alguns valores pra integrar ao meu sistema externo, a chave lifetime tem esse valor "147878163" que em horas seria 1 dia 17 dias e tal...

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Esse tempo esta em milisegundos. Se converter pra horas da 41.0772675 h

41h -24(um dia) = 17

ou seja 1 dia e 17 horas

Comment: Ah.... ok.. vou tentar aqui fazer isso, não sabia que estava milisegundos =D já posto o resultados

Comment: Tenta aí. Qualquer coisa pergunte aqui

Comment: Consegui! Ai ta somando por exemplo 30h   
agora preciso fazer isso ser 1 dia e 6h  -   
O código  -   
$total = ($lifetime/1000);
          $horas = (strlen(floor($total / 3600)) == 1) ? "0".floor($total / 3600)."":floor($total / 3600);
          $minutos = (strlen(floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60)) == 1) ? "0".floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60)."":floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
 $segundos = (strlen(floor($total % 60)) == 1) ? "0".floor($total % 60)."":floor($total % 60);
$lifetime = $horas . ":" . $minutos . ":" . $segundos;

como pula linha aqui ?